# Enabling brand icon in `cardNumber` type element in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

When using [Stripe elements](https://stripe.com/docs/elements), is there a way to *not* use the `card` element, but still get the auto brand icon show up somewhere (preferably in the `cardNumber` input field)?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In 2020+, you can use the `showIcon` option.

```js
const cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', {
  showIcon: true,
  placeholder: 'Card Number',
});
```

Comment: I was banging my head against the keyboard trying to figure out why the icon wasn't showing.  I guess stripe can't be bothered to document this feature even though all their examples show the icon and placeholder.

So thanks for this.

Comment: Thanks. `showIcon` works even now, in November 2021 :D

Comment: is there anyway to see what options are there, I'm trying to assign a card brand and the last four digit just to display user's default payment.

Comment: Thanks Atish, is there a way to make the icon show on the right instead of on the left?

Answer (score 32):

At the moment, no, there isn't. But Elements is still a very new product and we're very open to feedback! Please write to Stripe support at https://support.stripe.com/email to request this feature -- I can't promise it'll be implemented, but it'll certainly be considered.

edit: There isn't an option to have the `cardNumber` field show the brand icon automatically, but it's possible to implement this yourself by using the `brand` attribute in the element's [`change`](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/reference#element-on) event. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ywain/L96q8uj5/.

Comment: Ywain, I would file this behavior as a bug, since elements documentation has one option "hideIcon" which defaults to false. Took me a long time debugging until found this SO question, the icon should be there. Also, in the meantime, could you (or somebody else from Stripe) code something using the svg images instead of a custom font that makes the page even heavier to load ?

Comment: @sandre89 The `hideIcon` option only applies to the "all-in-one" `card` Element, not to the `cardNumber` element. I'll see if we can update the documentation to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

showIcon isn't a top level property - it's nested under options, so you'd have to do something like this:

```
    const OPTIONS = {
  showIcon: true,
};

return (
    <div className="App">
        <CardNumberElement options={OPTIONS} />
    </div>
  );
```

and it's only available for CardNumberElement, so you shouldn't be setting it for CardExpiryElement or CardCvcElement

- Direct from Stripe Discord Moderators.

Answer (score 1):

Just popping back in here. The appropriate option would be `hideIcon` as opposed to `showIcon`.

Stripe documents this in their JS Documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_element?type=card#elements_create-options-hideIcon

`hideIcon` is an Options property to `elements.create` as the doc above shows. So, for example, you would use this snippet:

```
var card = elements.create('card', {
  hidePostalCode: true,
  hideIcon: true,
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#F99A52',
      color: '#32315E',
      lineHeight: '48px',
      fontWeight: 400,
      fontFamily: '"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", sans-serif',
      fontSize: '15px',

      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#CFD7DF',
      }
    },
  }
});
card.mount('#card-element');
```

You can see this in my Fiddle if you'd like: https://jsfiddle.net/fiddler05/4qzcdw1p/18/

Comment: This answer could be more self-contained if you could've quoted the relevant sections of the linked documentation you've referred the OP and future visitors.

Comment: Hey @RohanBari you're correct! Allow me to clarify, the doc would link directly to hideIcon which is an Options set manually within elements.create. For example, you would write it such as this:

`var card = elements.create('card', {
  hidePostalCode: true,
  hideIcon: true,
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#F99A52',
      color: '#32315E',
      lineHeight: '48px',
      fontWeight: 400,
      fontFamily: '"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", sans-serif',
      fontSize: '15px',

      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#CFD7DF',
      }
    },
  }
});`

Comment: Nice, you can edit the answer and add the information. I'll remove my comment as well.