# How do I style stripe elements with error

Tags: css, stripe-payments

I was looking for a way to style stripe elements.

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46087546/3808307 very useful for the focus part

```
.StripeElement--focus
  outline: none
  border 1px solid green
```

How do I style the same element when there is an error? There is an .ElementsApp .InputElement.is-invalid, but that is not it, that does not refer to the same container.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

It's `.StripeElement--invalid`