# Professionally style a stripe elements credit card input form using stripe elements CSS?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am in need of any standard way of making the Stripe credit card input form from the Stripe docs look professional. Here is what it looks like with nothing done to it:

[image]

Stripe docs talk extensively about 'Stripe Elements' - a set of CSS that allows for easy styling - the problem is I have no idea how to apply it to this form.

Stripe give an [example](https://github.com/stripe-samples/connect-destination-charge), but [it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65159331/stripe-connect-test-app-says-no-accounts-have-payouts-enabled), and their [IRC currently is down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVMgz.jpg)

Here is the code for the form, which is [straight from the Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/creating-a-payments-page) (functionally, it works great, it just looks drab):

```html
<form id="payment-form">
  <div id="card-element">
    <!-- Elements will create input elements here -->
  </div>

  <!-- We'll put the error messages in this element -->
  <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  
  <br>
  <button id="submit">Pay</button>
</form>
```

I would like it to look like the one in the [docs](https://github.com/stripe-samples/connect-destination-charge/blob/master/.readme/screenshot.png?raw=true) (note that mine doesn't have an email field, but is otherwise very similar):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got it looking half respectable through trial and error of the different classes found in the [stripe example](https://github.com/stripe-samples/connect-destination-charge/blob/39268b8ee9e9cb1f3f929c823b5d301cc2bc1c9f/client/index.html#L38-L54), some bootstrap classes, and form border from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53125706/5783745). I'm sure there are (much) better looking forms, but here's what this results in:

[image]

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">

  <form id="payment-form">
    <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card:</label><br>
    <div id="card-element" class="form-control" style='height: 2.4em; padding-top: .7em;'>
      <!-- Elements will create input elements here -->
    </div>

    <!-- We'll put the error messages in this element -->
    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    
    <br>
    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Pay</button>
  </form>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
</div>
```